# SSL proxy pass with NGINX leading to bad gateway through Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

### Background

My setup is based on the following tutorial:

[Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and NGINX](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/)

TL;DR: (*italics: not covered by tutorial; personal adventure*)

- 3 Docker services for: nginx -> django -> postgres (arrow indicating dependency)
- Nginx proxy passes requests to exposed port in Django service.
- HTTP (non-SSL) requests working
- *require SSL connections by redirecting http -> https*

---

### Details

I've generated a self-signed certificate to test out ssl redirects with NGINX locally before trying to get it to work on a VPS in production. I'm quite new to working with NGINX and so I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong or how to diagnose problems.

Here's what I **want** to happen with the NGINX file I've provided below... *(spoilers: it doesn't)*:

1. Go to http://localhost
2. Get redirected to https://localhost
3. Warning from browser about a self-signed cert; accept warning and proceed
4. Site rendered fine, SSL redirect working!

But this isn't the case. I get a 502 Bad Gateway, and NGINX outputs the following logs:

```
prod_1  | 192.168.144.1 - - [03/Jun/2019:00:01:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 158 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0" "-"
prod_1  | 2019/06/03 00:01:44 [error] 8#8: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.144.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.144.3:8000/", host: "localhost"
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on or how to fix it? I feel like there's probably a whole bunch wrong with my conf file even outside of the SSL redirect, but I don't really know how to identify any problems. The conf file is below...

```
upstream mysite {
    server web:8000;
}

# redirect http traffic to https
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://mysite;
        proxy_ssl_server_name   on;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_redirect          off;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        alias /usr/src/site/assets/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/site/media/;
    }

    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certificates/site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/certificates/site.key;

    ssl_session_cache           builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

}
```

Comment: Is your upstream (Django) secure? My guess is that Django is http, but you have configured nginx to connect to it via https.

Comment: @chuex I'll have to look into that, I didn't realize I had to set up Django to be secure as well. Is there something specific/additional I need to do in terms of the NGINX conf file towards that end? Aside from that, I'll look into the Django docs on SSL connections

Comment: You don't necessarily have to make Django secure.  I'd just configure nginx to connect to it via http instead of https.

Comment: @chuex Do you mean `proxy_pass $http://mysite;`? Doesn't that undo the SSL connection?

Comment: that's not what your code above says. you have `https://mysite` in the config

Comment: @chuex right; I'm asking if you're suggesting to switch it to `http://mysite` - and also asking if that doesn't defeat the purpose of the https/ssl connection

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to match the protocols.  If Django is http, then you'll want nginx to talk to it using http.  If Django is https, then likewise you need nginx to talk to it via https.  Yes http is less secure between nginx and Django.  There are two schools of thought about communications on localhost - one is to use https to be secure, and the other is that localhost is already secure.  For example, does your Django instance talk to the local database using SSL?  If not, then will it matter if Django talks to nginx in plaintext?  Anyway, that's a whole other question.

Comment: @chuex So, matching the protocol does make it work, and I will gladly mark your answer as correct if you want to summarize our discussion into an answer post. Before you do, though, I would like to clarify my understanding... The stuff that's happening between the docker services can already be considered secure? If not, how would one go about doing what you mentioned - making sure Django talks to the db and nginx with ssl? This is my first time trying to get SSL to work, so I'm very interested in learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error

```
prod_1  | 2019/06/03 00:01:44 [error] 8#8: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.144.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.144.3:8000/", host: "localhost"
```

I would say it's likely that you have some kind of protocol mismatch between Nginx and Django.  It's likely that Django is expecting non-secure communication (http).  Your nginx configuration indicates that you have configured it to communicate with Django via https:

```
proxy_pass https://mysite;
```

My suggestion is to make sure that the communication between Nginx and Django is using the same protocol, either http or https.

Whether you want to use http or https is up to you.  There are two differing schools of thought on whether http is secure here.

The first school of thought is that http IS secure in this scenario, since the communication is within the same machine.

The second school of thought is to secure all communications, and to use https. However if you agree with this line of thinking, you will have to make sure that the communication between your web server and database is also using a secure protocol.  After all, you are only as secure as your weakest link.

I tend to lean towards the first school of thought. Though this is not necessarily what is appropriate for you.

Comment: To add to this, it was important for me to set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in my Django `settings.py` file to verify that the inner http request is being forwarded from https. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#ssl-https